# Rollback ID is not initialized yet

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, configuration

I want to run mongodb with the master setting turned on, so I can run Monstache and Elasticsearch for syncing data.

However, after running:

```
mongod --master
```

I repetitively get the following error message:

```
[ftdc] Rollback ID is not initialized yet.
```

Any ideas?